Using Docx4j Combine 2 Document
I want to combine two documents into a single file. For example, if my first document contains 2 pages and my second document contains 3 pages, I want to merge them into one document without mixing the content.
I tried the code below but it merges the documents in a way that mixes up the data. I want both documents to remain intact and in sequence within a single file.

As per previous posts on this topic, merging 2 or more Word documents is tricky in the general case, since you need to take care of all the related parts, differences in style definitions etc.
That said, you can use MergeDocx which is in Plutext's commercial Enterprise Docxj, at https://plutext.com/ to handle all of that for you.
Disclosure: that's my company.
Scroll down to the bottom of the page to download a trial.
